# How to make Wordpress image scale on mobile?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, image, mobile-website

I have some wordpress contents in my browser, the text scale nicely when it's on mobile but the image doesn't scale at all.

Example of how the website looks:

**On Desktop**
[image: Desktop website]

**On Mobile**

[image]

As you can see the image is not scaled properly like the text.

**This is how I insert the text and image in Wordpress:**

[image: Wordpress setup]

**Here's the code:**

```
<div style={{ width: '100%', overflowX: 'hidden', overflowY: 'scroll' }}>
<Segment basic>
  <Card
    style={{
      boxShadow: 'none',
      borderWidth: 0,
      paddingTop: '1em',
      margin: '0',
    }}
  >
    <Card.Content>
      <Image
        floated="left"
        size="large"
        avatar
        src={authors.filter(a => a.id === blog.author)[0].avatar_urls[48]}
      />
      <Card.Header>
        {authors.filter(a => a.id === blog.author)[0].name}
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Meta>
        {new Date(blog.date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)}
      </Card.Meta>
    </Card.Content>
  </Card>

  <Header
    as="h1"
    content={title}
    style={{
      fontSize: '2.5em',
      textAlign: 'left',
      marginBottom: '1em',
      paddingLeft: '20px',
    }}
  />
  <Segment
    basic
    style={{
      paddingBottom: '3em',
      fontSize: '1.2em',
      width: '100%',
    }}
  >
    {ReactHtmlParser(content)}
  </Segment>
</Segment>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Without actually seeing the printed HTML page and its CSS it's impossible to say. However, most responsive image sizing problems can be fixed by adding `max-width:100%` to your image's style definition. _(I say "most" because it can also enlarge images, so you need to not add it to every img element!)_

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try it out and see whats's the outcome.